# Radius Of Curvature Calculation

Tags: c#, math

How can I calculate the radius of curvature for consecutive points which are stored in a List. I am writing the code in c# but the algorithm is enough for me.

Comment: Wikipedia has an algorithm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_curvature_(applications)

Comment: You are probably better of asking this on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this answer: [How can I find the radius of a curve in any point?](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20081222054148AAP4kWt)

http://liutaiomottola.com/formulae/sag.htm